# How to pass bool value inside ActionLink (from view to controll)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, boolean

I've to pass a bool inside -> `"@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Like", new { id = Model.Id @*, Pass bool value here *@}".`

My method Like signature takes a `Guid Id` and a `bool` in parameter.

I tried with with following:

```
   bool passBool = true;
   @Html.ActionLink("Like!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, passBool}
   @Html.ActionLink("Disike!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, passBool = false}
```

But I receive it as null.

```
 public ActionResult Like(Guid id, bool? getBool) //gets null error without '?'
        {
            if (getBool == true){    

                return Content("Liked!");

            }else if (getBool == false){    

                return Content("Disiked!");
            }
```

I also tried to fix it trough a view model without success:

```
var liked = new Test.ViewModel.LikeViewModel {LikeDislike = true};

 @Html.ActionLink("Like!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, liked}
```

But it doesn't work since these bool values are still null when I pass them. Any idea how to pass a bool value from view to controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name the parameter you are passing so that it matches your controller action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Like!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id,getBool= passBool}
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, I don't use ViewModel inside that view. The model I use doesn't have bool property. That's why I tried to solve it by borrow a ViewModel via `var liked = new Test.ViewModel.LikeViewModel {LikeDislike = true};`. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by borrowed. Also, I don't recommend using HTTPGet (which is what you are doing) to do an action such as like/dislike. You should make a form and post such a value. Otherwise, a web crawler or automated tool could follow your link and 'like' things without meaning to.